# Is this the way to embed $G_1$, $G_2$ into the amalgamated product $G_1*_HG_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-product

Let $G_1,G_2,H$ be groups such that there are injective homomorphisms $f_i\colon H\to G_i$ for $i=1,2$. We know that there are injective homomorphisms $\iota_i \colon G_i\to G_1*G_2$, where $G_1*G_2$ is the free product. We can then consider N as the smallest normal subgroup of $G_1*G_2$ that contains all the elements of the form $\iota_1(f_1(h))\iota_2(f_2(h^{-1}))$ with $h\in H$ and then the amalgamated product is defined as $G_1*_HG_2:=(G_1*G_2)/N$. With the definiton clear (please correct me in anything if I'm wrong), I'm trying to prove that there are injective homomorphisms $j_i:G_i\to G_1*_HG_2$, $i=1,2$.

My first attempt was to consider the natural projection $\pi:G_1*G_2\to (G_1*G_2)/N$ and then proposed $j_i:=\pi|_{\iota_i[G_i]}\circ\iota_i$, so basically, just restrict the natural projection to the copy of each $G_i$ in $G_1*G_2$ and compose with the already existent inclusions.

Now, for the sake of having a simpler notation, let's call $G_i^{*}=\iota_i[G_i]$. Since the inclusions to the free product are already injective, it suffices to prove that the restricted natural projection behaves injectively. We have that $ker(\pi|_{G_i^*})=G_i^*\cap N$, so proving that it is injective is equivalent to each $G_i^*$ having trivial intersection with $N$, so let $x\in G_i^*\cap N$. The struggle comes with how general the definitons are, because for example, if $N$ was the subgroup generated by the same elements as before, then one would at least have an idea of how its elements would look like. However, we are taking the intersection of all **normal** subgroups that contain those elements, and so the only thing I know is that $x$ belongs to each of these subgroups. Also, given an arbitrary $g$, I would want to prove that $gxg^{-1}=e$, but the only thing I know is that it is again an element of $N$.

I know maybe I haven't achieved much progress, but I really don't know how to proceed, as I'm very new to this kind of topics. Any help is greatly appreciated and thanked for.

P.S. Is this topic not a little too advanced for an introductory group theory course? I feel as though my professor was teaching us topics that way are beyond the ones that would usually be teached in a first class of group theory.

Comment: Are you assuming the $f_i$ are injective? If you don’t, then you may not be able to embed into your construct, because for example you could have an $h\in H$ that maps to the trivial element of $G_1$ but not in $G_2$, in which case you must annihilate the nontrivial image in $G_2$.

Comment: Well that was not in my notes, but in that case I suppose they are.

Comment: Are you hoping for an “abstract nonsense” proof, or are you happy with a group-theoretic proof? This is usually established by giving a normal form for the elements of $G_1*_H G_2$: take, e.g., left coset representatives for (the image of) $H$ in $G_i$, and then the elements are of the form $g_{i_1}g_{j_1}\cdots g_{i_k}g_{j_k}h$, where $h\in H$ and other elements alternate between the families of coset represerntatives. You then show you have a group with the “obvious” product, and this easily is seen to contain copies of $G_1$ and $G_2$ (that intersect exactly at $H$).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, well I was hoping for someone to let me know whether I was in the right track or not. To be honest I have no idea if the function I proposed is actually injective. Also, unfortunately I have no Idea what you mean with abstract nonsense :/. I’m just really lost because of how much these topics are out of my reach and capability of understanding.

Comment: @BryanCastro ["Abstract nonsense"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_nonsense) is a technical term. Here it would mean deducing your result from the universal property of amalgamated products. Since you're already feeling at sea, it's probably best to ignore such notions for the moment, though it's necessary to come back to them later if you continue in algebra. [...]

Comment: [...] Anyway, Arturo is sketching how to construct a "concrete model" for $M$ for $G_1 \ast_H G_2$ where the required injectivity is clear: the set of lists $(g_{i_1}, g_{j_1}, \ldots, g_{i_k}, g_{j_k}, h)$ with the properties he mentioned. The heart of the matter is to prove this model is isomorphic to your abstractly defined $G_1 \ast_H G_2$. There's a map $G_1 \ast G_2 \to M$; you'd need to show it's surjective with the correct kernel.

Comment: For your final question, the answer is probably yes, this topic is way too advanced for an introductory course in group theory.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson: While the construction does in fact give a model for $M$, that much is not necessary to establish that the canonical functions into $G_1*_H G_2$ are one-to-one: if you can find *any* group $K$ into which you can embed $G_1$ and $G_2$ in such a way that the images of $H$ coincide, then that implies the embeddings into $G_1*_H G_2$ are one-to-one; that is, we would not need to prove that the group constructed has the universal property to deduce what is sought for here.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Good point, I wasn't thinking about the fragment the question is asking about. It does make the question a little more reasonable.